# Insert several rows and problem with Return

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I wanted to write myself a function that makes it possible to Insert several rows into one list.

```
matrix = Table[i*(j + 2), {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
vector1 = Range[10, 12];
vector2 = Range[20, 22];
```

This one worked perfectly fine:

```
Do[matrix = Insert[matrix, {vector1, vector2}[[i]], 1], {i, 2}];
```

Then I started straightforward with:

```
InsertRows[vectors_List, matrix_List, position_Integer] :=
Do[
matrix = Insert[matrix, vectors[[i]], position]
, {i, Length@vectors}]
```

This does not work. After little search I found that I have to force Do[] to return some value. But the same search also highlighted that it is not recommended to use Return[].

So here are my questions:

1. How to define a function that can insert several rows. If there is an approach without a loop, I was happy to see it.
2. How to properly define this function with the Do[] Loop.

Comment: What error do you get with your version of `InsertRows` when I copy and paste it into mathematica for  vectors_list and matrix_list, "list" I get lower case l's

Comment: I changed _list to _List. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the main issue is that you cannot (readily*) modify the actual argument to a function Try this:

```
 InsertRows[vectors_List, matrix0_List,position_Integer] := 
   Module[{matrix},
       matrix = matrix0;
       Do[matrix = Insert[matrix, vectors[[i]], position], {i, 
           Length@vectors}]; matrix]
```

usage: `matrix = InsertRows[{vector1, vector2}, matrix, 1]`

*of course it can be done using `HoldFirst` but its best avoided:
(note no `_List` on `matrix` )

```
 InsertRows[matrix_, vectors_List, position_Integer] := Module[{},
      Do[matrix = Insert[matrix, vectors[[i]], position], {i, 
         Length@vectors}]]
 SetAttributes[InsertRows, HoldFirst]
```

usage: `InsertRows[matrix,{vector1, vector2}, 1]` modifies the arg and returns `Null`.

Of course in either case the `Do` loop is best replaced per @image_doctor's answer --  another variant is `Join[matrix[[;; position - 1]], vectors, matrix[[position ;;]]]`

Comment: Thank you very much for both your answers. I gave image_doctor the Question Solved sign since you already have more reputation ;).

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of approaches without using a loop, but utilising `Flatten` and `FlattenAt`:

```
FlattenAt[Insert[matrix, {vector1, vector2}, 2], 2]
```

> {{3, 4, 5}, {10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}, {6, 8, 10}, {9, 12, 15}}

```
ir[vecs_, matrix_, pos_] := Flatten[{matrix[[1 ;; pos - 1]], vecs, matrix[[pos ;; -1]]}, 1]

ir[{vector1, vector2}, matrix, 2]
```

> {{3, 4, 5}, {10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}, {6, 8, 10}, {9, 12, 15}}